# Java operator precedence and shifting

Tags: java

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x =10;
        int a = x << 2-33;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

could any one please explain how this code snippet is working(debug)
and the output is 20.

if there are parenthesis for X << 2 then the simplification is easy but without parenthesis ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Java [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), `x << 2-33` means `x << (2-33)` (the "additive" group of operators is higher in the table than the "shift" group).

2 - 33 = -31, and shifts takes their shift count modulo the size of the integer that they are shifting (the only options for the size are 32 or 64, anything smaller than an `int` would be converted to an `int` first). -31 modulo 32 is 1 (note that this kind of modulo is not quite the same as the *remainder* operator `%`), so you get 10 left-shifted by 1 which is 20.

Comment: maybe the *wording* of the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) is better: "If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111)."